I want to ask for good references of linear algebra over rational numbers?
My current studies in algebraic number theory have led me to observe the frequent interplay between linear algebra concepts over the field of rational numbers. This connection becomes particularly evident in Chapter 9, 'Algebraic and Transcendental Numbers,' of Ivan Niven's book 'Irrational Numbers.'  For instance, the theorem discussed in this chapter
LEMMA 7.1. Any r + 1 linear forms in r indeterminates
with rational coefficients are linearly dependent over the ra-
tionals.
Remark. This is a well-known result, and so we give
a reference but not a proof. The matrix of the linear
forms cannot have rank greater than r, and this is less
than the number of forms. For further details, see any
book on the theory of equations, for example, J. M.
Thomas, Theory of Equations, Theorem 27.7, p. 49, Mc-
Graw-Hill.
But this reference suggested by IVAN NIVEN, I can't find it on Internet, what can I do?
I want to find references to strengthen myself in the preliminaries for being strong in Algebraic and Transcendental number theory.
I am highly motivated to contribute to the field of Algebraic and Transcendental Number Theory by tackling challenging problems such as the transcendence of $e + \pi$. My aim is to contribute to the ongoing effort of reducing the number of unsolved problems in this fascinating branch of mathematics.

That statement in Lemma 7.1 is true over any field, not just the field $\mathbb Q$.
The more general statement is this:

For any field $\mathbb F$, any $r$ dimensional vector space $V$ over $\mathbb F$, and any $s > r$, any $s$ elements of the dual space $\text{Hom}(V,\mathbb F)$ are linearly dependent over $\mathbb F$.

And since $\text{Hom}(V,\mathbb F)$ is also an $r$ dimensional vector space (over $\mathbb F$), the still more general statement is this:

For any field $\mathbb F$, any $r$-dimensional vector space $W$ over $\mathbb F$, and any $s > r$, any $s$ elements of $W$ are linearly dependent over $\mathbb F$.

You should be able to find this in any abstract linear algebra textbook; there's shouldn't be any need to look for one that is special to the field $\mathbb Q$.
